# Why can't I delete a sheet after copying it?

Tags: excel, vba

I have code which is created in an excel document as it can be 300 lines which are all similar, I would like to copy a range from one sheet to another then delete that second sheet. I managed to copy from one sheet to another but my delete isn't working I need to do this all on one line.

This is what I have done

```
Sheets("100614_2019010915_1min").Range("A2:Q60").Copy Destination:=Sheets("100614_2019010914_1min").Range("A61").Sheets("100614_2019010915_1min").Delete
```

Comment: You can't copy/paste/delete all on one line.  Put the delete part on a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Sheets("100614_2019010915_1min").Range("A2:Q60").Copy 
Destination:=Sheets("100614_2019010914_1min").Range("A61")
Sheets("100614_2019010915_1min").Delete
```

OR:

```
Sheets("100614_2019010915_1min").Range("A2:Q60").Copy Sheets("100614_2019010914_1min").Range("A61")
Sheets("100614_2019010915_1min").Delete
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation as to why this works where OP's code doesn't.

Comment: BruceWayne has already explained why my code doesn't work underneath the question

Answer (score 2):

I believe you watned this:

```
Sheets("100614_2019010915_1min").Range("A2:Q60").Copy Sheets("100614_2019010914_1min").Range("A61")
Sheets("100614_2019010915_1min").Delete
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation as to why this works where OP's code doesn't.

Comment: @BruceWayne has already explained this underneath the question